# Using devise helpers in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

Is there any way to use devise's controller helpers in model namely user_signed_in? I have tried adding the following line to my user model, but that doesn't seem to work:

```
include Devise::Controllers::Helpers
```

More specifically, I want users to be allowed to be created without password, for which I am implementing the method 'password_required?'. In that method I want to check (before creating the user) if another user is creating that user, or weather he/she is signing up. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

You cant access controller helper within the model. however you can build an association between users that would allow you to create users on behalf of one another

take a look at rbates screencast on how to implement it

http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association